# Do Per-Request (Custom) Roles exist for ASP.NET and ActiveDirectory?

Tags: asp.net, roles, security-roles

My vision includes having globally defined roles which are pushed from AD but also I'd like to be able to add to Context.User.IsInRole("ATransientRoleForThisDocumentOnly") and have that work...

I thought about pushing roles into the Thread.CurrentPrincipal and passing in Context.User.Identity and an array of roles but I was concerned about getting all the ADRoles that you get out of the box, I really just want to add some AdHoc roles that will live for the lifetime of the request.

Does that seem possible? All Role manager methods are static so even if I did custom role manager how would that manager know that for document-id #1 that you're reader... while on document #2 you're read/write?

Answer (score 1):

Inherit from a Security class that allows you to override CreatePermission, for instance CodeAccessSecurityAttribute and return this :

```
public override IPermission CreatePermission()
{
  return new PrincipalPermission(string.Empty, "MyCustomRole");
}
```